# Java AudioSystem prevent loop from repeating before song finishes

Tags: java, audio

I have a program that will ask the user which songs they want to play out of a list of available songs and after the user selects one once the song finishes it asks the user which song they want to play again. My question is how do I prevent the loop from asking the user which song they want to play until the selected song is finished so they don't repeat?

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] pathnames;
    File MusicFileChosen;
    String musicDir;
    boolean songComplete = false;

    pathnames = ProgramMap.musicDir.list();

    // Print the names of files and directories
    for (int ListNum = 0; ListNum < pathnames.length; ListNum++) {
        System.out.println(ListNum + 1 + ". " + pathnames[ListNum]);
    }


   for (int playlistLength = 0; playlistLength < pathnames.length; playlistLength++){
        if (!songComplete) {
            System.out.println("Which Song would you like to play?");
            int musicChoice = input.nextInt();
            musicDir = ProgramMap.userDir + "\\src\\Music\\" + pathnames[musicChoice - 1];
            MusicFileChosen = new File(musicDir);
            PlaySound(MusicFileChosen, pathnames[musicChoice - 1]);

        }
    }
}
public static void PlaySound(File sound, String FileName){
    try{
        // Inits the Audio System
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

        AudioInputStream AudioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);

        //Finds and accesses the clip
        clip.open(AudioInput);

        //Starts the clip
        clip.start();

        System.out.println("Now Playing " + FileName);

        clip.drain();


    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error playing music");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [LineListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineListener.html). Then, register and listen for [LineEvent.Type.CLOSE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineEvent.Type.html).

By the way, you might do better to use `SourceDataLine` than `Clip`. Maybe not a big deal, but given what you've coded, there could be audible lag, depending on the size of the file, every time you open a clip and load the complete file into memory (this has to be completed before playing can start). The `SourceDataLine` will commence playing almost immediately (only loads one buffer before starting to play) and only consumes the one buffer of memory instead of the entire sound file.

A lot of people that are new to `javax.sound.sampled` are wary of using `SourceDataLine` but it really isn't that much more difficult to code than a `Clip`, and for the use you are showing, it would be a better fit.